# Меня огорчает цветовая схема Меты

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, дизайн

Давайте пересмотрим цветовую схему Меты? Эта в некоторых местах очень неудобна.

#### 1. На Мете, на странице «Знаки» текст на посещённых ссылках нечитаем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### 2. Форматирование цитаты и внутристрочное выделение кода сливаются.

> пример пример пример `код` пример `код код`

#### 3. Посещенные ссылки трудно отличить от обычного текста.

Пример строки со [ссылкой](http://unexistent.url), которую вы точно не посещали. А вот [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), которую наверняка посещали.

Comment: По-моему, сейчас проблема уже не актуальна. По крайней мере, в FF и Chrome я не вижу различий в отображении метки в зависимости от посещения её.

Comment: @alexolut ага, и с кодом внутри цитаты всё хорошо. И со ссылкой.